# error con el setBackgroundcolor en el onitemclicklistener

Tags: kotlin

quiero que cuando el usuario seleccione un item, este cambie de color, pero al cambiar del color ese item, cambia otro item de igual manera, no se porque ocurre este error este es el codigo

estoy usando un list_view y un simpleCursorAdapter, con un LoaderManager, acontinuacion el codigo

```
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>,AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{
        var cols=listOf<String>(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.LOOKUP_KEY
        ).toTypedArray()
        lateinit  var listView1:ListView
        lateinit var adapter:SimpleCursorAdapter
        lateinit var cursor:Cursor
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            val binding=ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
            setContentView(binding.root)
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission.READ_CONTACTS) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,Array(1){ Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS},111)
            }else {
                var from=listOf<String>(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER).toTypedArray()
                var to = intArrayOf(R.id.name,R.id.number)
    
                adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                    R.layout.list_item_contacts,
                    null,
                    from,
                    to,0)
                listView1=findViewById<ListView>(R.id.listView1) as ListView
    
                LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(1, null, this)
            }
            listView1.onItemClickListener=this
        }
    
        override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
            if(requestCode==111 && grantResults[0]==PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                LoaderManager.getInstance(this).initLoader(1,null,this)
    
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor> {
            return CursorLoader(applicationContext,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                cols,
                null,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME
            )
    
        }
    
        override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>, data: Cursor?) {
            adapter.swapCursor(data)
            listView1.adapter=adapter
    
    
        }
    
        override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>) {
            adapter.swapCursor(null)
            listView1.adapter=adapter
    
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        override fun onItemClick(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
    
           
            view?.setBackgroundColor(Color.argb(96,189,189,189))
    
        }
    
    }
```

y este es el resultado [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ej: al precionar el nombre de "angela" se marca el nombre de "centro de atencion"

no se si hay alguna otra función que desconozca, cabe destacar que estoy iniciando en la programación Android, si me pudieran ayudar, les agradecería

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sucede que el ListView recicla las views para mejorar la performance. Es decir que varios items usan la misma view y por ello al cambiarle el background afectas a más de un item. La solución más simple (pero mas costosa en terminos de performance) es crear un adapter que infle una view para cada item. Para ello debes remplazar esta parte

```
adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    R.layout.list_item_contacts,
    null,
    from,
    to, 0
)
```

por esto

```
adapter = object : SimpleCursorAdapter(
    this,
    R.layout.list_item_contacts,
    null,
    from,
    to,
    0
) {
    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int) = position
    override fun getViewTypeCount() = count
}
```

Pero hay un problema más grave y es que todo tu código se ve cómo si fuera de hace cinco años. Si estás iniciando en android no te sirve aprender esas APIs que están obsoletas o en desuso. Te facilitaré documentación sobre las APIs que te servirán para reemplazar ese código:

- para pedir permisos hay una nueva API llamada [ActivityResult](https://medium.com/@ajinkya.kolkhede1/requesting-runtime-permissions-using-new-activityresult-api-cb6116551f00)
- LoaderManager fue reemplazado por la librería [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle) que además puedes [combinarla con los kotlin flows](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda)
- el listview y el adapter puedes reemplazarlo por las [composable lists](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/lists)
- pero lo mejor será que comiences [estudiando jetpack compose](https://developer.android.com/courses/pathways/compose). Esta librería supone un cambio importante en la forma de desarrollar aplicaciones. Aún está en beta pero seguramente será estable cuando termines de aprenderla.
- y si quieres estar actualizado no puedes perderte el [próximo Google I/O](https://events.google.com/io/?lng=es-419)